# How do I permanently delete failed prisma migrations in productions to keep it in sync with my local prisma migrations folder?

Tags: prisma, remix.run

I'm experiencing an error while deploying my remix app to fly via github actions.
I recently altered one of my schemas, which led to the failed migration. I have deleted the migrations in the prisma/migrations folder and the local _prisma_migrations table and did a fresh prisma migrate dev. When I push to github I get an error that one of the migrations that I deleted could not be applied. How do I delete it completely in the production environment?[image]

Comment: Each environment (local vs production) keeps track of it's own migration state. Did you delete the migrations from production as well?

Comment: I deleted the local one then did one migrate dev and pushed the migration; I don't know how to delete the production one

Comment: You can invoke `npx prisma studio` and delete them manually or use a DROP table query to drop the table